# Issue with javascript with use passive listeners

Tags: javascript, html

as many topics has with this issue i can't figure out how to manage it correct in two .js files
For the one file i will post what i do and it doesnt show any errors anymore but i'm not sure is it correct.
Main error that i receive is:
Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance
Consider marking your touch and wheel event listeners as passive to improve your page's scroll performance.

Select2.js and Jquery.js.
`https://pastebin.com/61yjrdri - Select2.js https://pastebin.com/VNCwLJLN - Jquery.js`

so what i try in Select2.js was like this:

```
this.$element[0].addEventListener(
        'DOMAttrModified',
        self._syncA, **{passive: true}**
        false
      );
```

It removes me the message error, but i'm not sure is the correct way to fix it.